# Google +1 button causes x-domain JS error in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-plus-one

I followed the steps exactly on Google PlusOne page and I got an error message like this in Chrome console:

> Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL xx with URL xx
>   Domains, protocols and ports must match.

However, it works in FF, even IE9. Ironic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same problems comes with their AdSense javascript. You have no chance to fix this without their help, and you can't do anything at all with it

Comment: That's sad. I found a post about this created in Aug, 2011. It's been 3 months... How long have you been experiencing this problem?

Comment: @Xi.: Since the start I'm using AdSense